# How do I update PHP version, 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.6 to latest version?

Tags: package-management, php, joomla

I got this warning in Joomla:

> Your PHP version, 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.6, is only receiving security fixes from the PHP project at this time. This means your PHP version will soon no longer be supported. We recommend planning to upgrade to a newer PHP version before it reaches end of support on 2020-11-30. Joomla will be faster and more secure if you upgrade to a newer PHP version. Please contact your host for upgrade instructions.

Comment: Do you have ssh access to your host server OR are you on Cpanel or something?

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 different options (in order of least to most effort):

1. As you're running a Canonical/Ubuntu supported version of PHP, you're guaranteed at least 5 years of support (and thus security patches) from Canonical, regardless of the PHP project's policy.  You can literally do nothing yet still have a supported version of PHP until 2023.
2. Many people install the [ondrej PHP PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) and install PHP from there.  I do not have an opinion over this particular PPA but I have had to help others debug problems caused indirectly by the PPA.
3. Upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04.1 which bumps PHP to v7.4.